# Permission Denied on Binding socket to local address in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm attempting to bind my python socket to a specific IP address on my system (the same as my host), I first figure out what my host's IP address is and then bind it with the port number (which is 8080). I keep getting a Permission Denied error anytime I call the bind function and I have no clue why. It comes up when I use sudo as well.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind((ip_addr, int(PORT)))

print(f"Listening at {ip_addr} : {PORT}")
sock.listen(5)
```

I was getting the same error before I got my IP Lookup function working. It had been assigning the address 127.0.1.1, to which I also got a permission denied error. It doesn't get this error if I

```
sock.bind(('', int(PORT)))

or

sock.bind(('localhost', int(PORT)))
```

However, I can't use these as I'm attempting to connect to other hosts on my network. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: You might get that error if you are already running some process using that port in your localhost. Sometimes you are testing and left other instances of your program running.

Comment: Be aware at firewalls too. They may block you on other hosts or in your own if you use your own IP.

Comment: Thanks @progmatico! I added a firewall rule and it fixed it, thanks all for your suggestions!!

Comment: @progmatico No you mightn't. 'Already in use' is a separate error from 'permission denied'. This is a firewall issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing @MarquisofLorne . Recalling the error message from my memory alone wasn't very precise indeed. But the two errors are common annoyances when doing this. Comment should have said "You may also get an error if..."